# what is the exact use and implementation of singleton class?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I know the singleton class does not allow to create more than one object. but as per my below code i can create as many objects as possible.

```
class Singleton
{
  private :
   static Singleton *m_Instance;
   Singleton()
   {
     cout<<"In defailt constructor"<<endl;
   }
   Singleton(int x)
   {
      i = x;
      cout<<"in param const"<<endl;
   }
 public:
   static int i;
   static Singleton* createInstance()
   {
      if(!m_Instance)
        m_Instance = new Singleton(20);
      Singleton sing;
      return m_Instance;
   }
};
int Singleton::i=0;
Singleton* Singleton::m_Instance = NULL;
int main()
{

    Singleton *pt = Singleton::createInstance();
    return 1;
}
```

Here I am able to create an object in the static function (as i can access constructor within the class) then where is the concept of Single object?

Comment: singletons are un-necessary in c++. return a static object from a function.

Comment: What reference are you using for a Singleton? The GoF book in 1995 has C++ code examples and they don't look like this.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a singleton for the simple reason that you deliberately wrote something that isn't a singleton.

The idea is that you write the `instance` function so that it will only create one instance, and write other members so that they don't create any. Then, since they're the only functions that could create any instances, there will only be one.

If you remove the dodgy `Singleton sing;`, then you'll have a singleton implementation - only one instance will be created, the first time someone calls the function.

As with all attempts to implement this anti-pattern in C++, there are problems: the object is never destroyed, and the initialisation isn't thread-safe. There are various other approaches, each with their own drawbacks. I suggest you avoid global variables altogether, whether or not you dress them up as singletons or other anti-patterns.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of single object comes when in your code, every time you need an instance of your Object, instead of using:

```
Singleton *myOwnSingleton=  new Singleton(20);
```

You should always use:

```
Singleton *pt = Singleton::createInstance();
```

As the constructor is inaccesible outside of the class, the only way to create a Singleton   is by `Singleton::createInstance()`, and if you read the code, only the first time that we call `Singleton::createInstance()` a new instance is created.
All subsequent calls to this method will return the already created object. So in all your execution you will only have one instance created.

But of course... you should delete the line

```
Singleton sing;
```

because it is a wrong utilization of Singleton. If you create a class called CAR but without wheels... it is not a car. And you make a class called singleton, but... with two objects of the same type. It's not beauty!

Comment: you mean to say we can create many object but it does not become singleton. right? i have one more doubt. is there any way to check whether object is being used or not. if not used how to delete it. I want to clarify this for singleton only.

Comment: @sasikala: What do you mean by "used"? It won't be created unless someone calls the `instance` function; then it will last forever. If you want to control its lifetime in some other way, then it's no longer a singleton.

Comment: in my code i called static function and created a static instance and i never do any operations. After some lines of code in main, i see that static instance is not needed anymore and i want delete it before program terminates. in that situation how can i delete it.

Comment: You could `delete createInstance()`.  Taking a step back, yes you can create an extra `Singleton sign;` inside `createInstance()`, but that's because `createInstance()` is a member function of `Singleton` and therefore unrestricted in accessing the `private` constructor.  The important thing is that if you write `createInstance()` properly, other functions - that aren't members or friends - have to respect your intent to have only one instance and use `createInstance()` to access it.

Comment: when u want to delete, just use in the main:

Singleton *pt = Singleton::createInstance();
delete pt;

but never hit again Singleton::createInstance();,    because it will fail.

Comment: the other option is create a method called DeleteInstance()

static Singleton* DeleteInstance()
   {
      if(!m_Instance)
      {
        delete m_Instance;
        m_Instance = NULL;
      }
   }

Comment: thanks Tirma for your answer and Tony i have doubt here. you have written it as "if you write createInstance() properly" what does it mean? one more doubt is "i called static function and created a static instance and i never do any operations. After some lines of code in main, i see that static instance is not needed anymore and i want delete it before program terminates." how can i check whether object is in use or not?

Comment: thanks to you. Set the question as solved if it is ;)